# Channel connected event is being fired on connect failure

Tags: netty

I am facing a weird problem where channel.connect returns failure in ChannelFuture but also fires the channel connected event. I am using 3.2.7. I referred to the NioWorker#RegisterTask class. I think the run method should return after the catch block. Below is the stack traces that might help

**Stack trace for failure on ChannelFuture:**

```
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:381)   
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:372)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:334)  
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$1.operationComplete(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:157)  
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:381)  
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:367)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setSuccess(DefaultChannelFuture.java:316)  
at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$ChannelCloseFuture.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:351)  
at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:188)  
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.setClosed(NioSocketChannel.java:146)  
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.close(NioWorker.java:592)  
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.close(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:415)  
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:379)  
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:299)  
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)  
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Stack trace for CONNECTED event:**

```
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:783)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.channelConnected(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:183)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:110)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelConnected(Channels.java:233)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker$RegisterTask.run(NioWorker.java:792)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processRegisterTaskQueue(NioWorker.java:258)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:200)
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you open a bug report at http://github.com/netty/netty ?

Comment: Created an issue with #249. So would the fix be to return from the catch block in NioWorker#RegisterTask.run?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in netty. I just commited the fix and it will be part of the next release (3.4.0.Beta1).

See [1]

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/249